# bash /usr/bin/find -name or -not -name, got 'No such file or directory'

Tags: bash, find

The cronjob always got 'No such file or directory'.

```
/usr/bin/find /store/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name data_r -exec /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete '{}/' '{}_bak' \; >/dev/null
```

The error is:

```
/usr/bin/find: ‘/store/master/data_w’: No such file or directory
```

The parameter is -name data_r, why got error on data_w ?

Answer (score 1):

You have instructed `find` to search in `/store/` for directories matching the `-name`.  In order to do that, it will visit all the eligible directories -- it has to!

Now, as to why you are receiving an error message, it could be either because `data_w` is a dangling symlink, or (much less likely) because `data_w` existed, but then disappeared.

If you want to avoid traversing this particular directory entry, add something like `-name data_w -prune -o` to skip it.

Otherwise, getting errors from traversing a directory hierarchy isn't altogether unusual.